# How to get private key on IOS used for SSL traffic?

Tags: ios, ssl, wireshark

I need to debug/view an IOS app's encrypted traffic, so i had captured SSL encrypted TCP packets via pirni. and trying to decrypt them via Wireshark. but i need session key for that. is there any way to export private key in IOS to be used with wireshark as in PKCS format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The private key in any SSL connection is on the *server*.

Even if there were a private key on the client, it's only used for *authentication* not *encryption*.

Comment: Yes you were right. Thank you. I was looking at wrong type of keys. session keys were right, not private keys.